# Não consigo deletar usuários

Tags: php

Por alguma razão, não sei qual, ao tentar deletar qualquer usuário, cai na mensagem de que foi deletado com sucesso, porém não deleta! Não importa qual seja o usuário. Neste caso uso o admin como sendo o ID 1 e deveria cair na mensagem de erro de que não se pode deletar admins.

Se alguém puder ajudar...

```
<?php
  require_once ("../config/db.php");
  require_once ("../config/conexion.php");
  include('is_logged.php');
  $action = (isset($_REQUEST['action'])&& $_REQUEST['action'] !=NULL)?$_REQUEST['action']:'';
if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    $user_id=intval($_GET['id']);
    $query=mysqli_query($con, "select * from users where user_id='".$user_id."'");
    $rw_user=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $count=$rw_user['user_id'];
    if ($count!==1){
        if ($delete1=mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id='".$user_id."'")){
        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <strong>Aviso!</strong> Dados elimidados com sucesso.
        </div>
        <?php 
    }else {
        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <strong>Erro!</strong> Algo de errado aconteceu, tente novamente.
        </div>
        <?php

    }

    } else {
        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <strong>Erro!</strong> Não se pode deletar o usuário administrador. 
        </div>
        <?php
    }



}
```

Comment: Já debugou a variável $user_id? Pode ser que o valor via GET não esteja chegando e a variável esteja vazia, fazendo rodar um SQL assim: DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id=''

Comment: quando eu coloquei f ($count > 1) não deleta nenhum usuário, com o erro dizendo que não se pode deletar administradores